# Select most frequent month of a year in SQLITE3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like the following-

```
year        month       frequency 
----------  ----------  ----------
2501        04          33        
2501        03          911       
2503        12          377       
2503        11          3956      
2503        10          1409      
2503        07          161       
2503        06          66        
2504        03          46
```

How to get the most frequent month of each year to produce

```
year        month       frequency 
----------  ----------  ----------      
2501        03          911            
2503        11          3956           
2504        03          46
```

Comment: `select year,min(month),frequency from table group by year,frequency`

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is to use `join` :

```
select t1.* 
from t t1 join (select year, max(freq) freq from t group by year) t2
on t1.year = t2.year and t1.freq = t2.freq
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ac55a/4)

Answer (score 1):

The following query provides your solution. [SQLFiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/399cb/8)

```
select year, month, max(frequency) frequency
from mytable 
group by year
```

**UPDATE:** 
Your required output had columns `year, month, frequency` where `frequency` was the maximum value of frequency per year. So `max(frequency) frequency` assigns the alias `frequency` to the query output so that it matches your requirement. Without the alias, the columns would be `year, month, max(frequency)`. Here is the [wiki on SQL aliases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)).

Comment: Only in SQLite 3.7.11 or later.

Comment: thanks! it works! but i don't understand what does  max(frequency) frequency mean? is there any documentation on this?

Comment: @user3810193: I updated my answer to address your doubt.